# Is there a way to change sound output in terminal?

Tags: audio, hdmi, solus

I'm talking about this:

[image: Raven sidebar]

The thingies arent clickable. Is there a terminal command I can use for a shortcut if not possible from the GUI?

I'm either using the in-built speakers or the same HDMI output each time.

Comment: I've not kept up with how your particular distro routes sound these days, maybe see if `alsamixer` is installed and does something useful for you?

Comment: It's installed and I am able to open it. But sadly I feel like I havent figured it out in a way where I could enter a command without entering the interface. Maybe I should have clarified that I can change my sound output, it just takes a bit more clicking than I want to, binding a Linux command to a key-press would be what I'm looking for. Or am I just not using alsamixer correctly?

Comment: You might want `amixer` instead. It runs entirely in CLI, using commands and options to adjust the settings you want.